# Python Pandas dataframe strip a specific key out of dict inside list in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called `get_groups_df` with several columns but I am having an issue with this particular column `links`. It seems that in this column that each row is a list with a dictionary inside Like the following:

```
get_groups_df.links[0:]
0    [{'action': 'GET', 'href': 'https://api.mysource.com/groups/asdfadsfa/users', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'users'}]
1    [{'action': 'GET', 'href': 'https://api.mysource.com/groups/eweasdxcv/users', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'users'}]
2    [{'action': 'GET', 'href': 'https://api.mysource.com/groups/aeasdfse/users', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'users'}]
3    [{'action': 'GET', 'href': 'https://api.mysource.com/groups/asfesfsas/users', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'users'}]
```

My goal is to just extract the `'href'` portion so all that's left is the `https...` portion like this:

```
df['links']

  links
0 https://api.mysource.com/groups/asdfadsfa/users 
1 https://api.mysource.com/groups/eweasdxcv/users
2 https://api.mysource.com/groups/aeasdfse/users 
3 https://api.mysource.com/groups/asfesfsas/users
```

I know how to extract extract a single one like `get_groups_df.links[0][0]['href']` and `get_groups_df.links[1][0]['href']` would get the second one but this is specific and would like to apply this to the column.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor like:

```
get_groups_df['links'].str[0].str['href']
```

where the `[0]` means first element in your list for each row, not the row number

Or you could use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to remove the list-like cell and then create dataframe from the result:

```
pd.DataFrame(get_groups_df['links'].explode().tolist())['href']
```

both gives

```
0    https://api.mysource.com/groups/asdfadsfa/users
1    https://api.mysource.com/groups/eweasdxcv/users
2     https://api.mysource.com/groups/aeasdfse/users
Name: href, dtype: object
```

The second solution could be usefull if you have more than one element in each list

Comment: Great answer.  This solved my issue. Still new at dictionaries. @Ben.T